Автозапуск EXE файла на Windows 11
Задался таким вопросом:
Можно ли поставить exe файл в автозапуск так, чтобы он запускался раньше, чем окно ввода пароля для пользователя? Типа фейк админ-панель Windows 11 запускается раньше, чем обычное окно ввода и перехватывает данные.
